# Openfire - MySQL storage engine: InnoDB or MyISAM?

Tags: mysql, innodb, openfire, myisam

I am wondering whether the storage engine of MySQL should be InnoDB or MyISAM.
Today, Default Engine is Innodb on Mysql. But i read in the post

https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/45108

that Myisam is performing better.

Have any idea what to use innodb or myisam for openfire chat?

Comment: Wow, I haven't read that post yet, but I'm stunned (and impressed) that this question is being asked in 2016. I'll read it over, but I'll put 10:1 odds on the right answer being InnoDB (even if this is technically an opinion-based question).

Comment: The gist of that post seems to be "I noticed that in my environment, MyISAM could do 50 times more inserts on this one specific table than InnoDB. In spite of all the reasons OpenFire is not supposed to be configured to use MyISAM and is specifically set up to use InnoDB by default, will using MyISAM break OpenFire if I force that setting?"

Comment: And there were 2 responses: 1) It should work, or at least it does for me. and 2) "I had a similarly vague experience where changing the engine to MyISAM seemed to fix it. Maybe MyISAM is better, but I haven't really tested beyond this one observation."  So the article isn't really an endorsement for MyISAM as being better for OpenFire, as much as it is one person noticing a difference and asking if it would be OK to use MyISAM, and another person saying "Hey, I also had a weird experience like that."

Comment: It is much more likely that in both cases, they had something misconfigured, and that 5 years and 3 versions later, MySQL has made InnoDB better at being awesome even when not configured correctly.

Comment: Also, remember that the storage engine is set at the table level, not the db level, so if you did have some reason to assume that reads/writes to one specific table was suffering due to InnoDB, you can always change that one table to MyISAM, leave the rest alone, and see if it makes a difference. No need to pick one or the other for the whole DB (unless you're picking InnoDB, because it's the right choice, but you *could* set a specific table to MyISAM if you really wanted to)

Comment: I would suggest that Openfire has not re-tuned its usage of MySQL to make better use of InnoDB.  For example, batch inserts and batch transactions eliminate most of the "93ms per insert" quoted in the link.  A blind replacement of InnoDB for MyISAM is unfair.  (As would be going the other direction.)

Comment: lots of comment make me more confused :-(

Answer (score 0):

Using openfire and InnoDB is the engine that I am using and it works fine. You can use InnoDB.

Comment: Are you sure? That link he posted had three question marks in its title...

Comment: Yeah have been using it for more than 8 months now.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend InnoDB but it will largely be dependent on what type of application you are developing.  MyISAM does not support transactions and uses table level locking over row level locking so it is only more performant in a very small number of instances.